# Docker-Desktop on Linux gui apps

Tags: docker

Is it possible to use gui apps in Docker-Desktop?

I used to use it in Docker engine using commands

```
docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY --runtime nvidia -e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all --net host --name odroid-ROS2 ubuntu:20.04
```

But in Docker-Desktop, I got "The path /tmp/.X11-unix is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker" error...

Comment: Are you on a native-Linux host?  Docker Desktop runs Docker inside a Linux VM; if you're already running Linux, you don't need this VM, and using the Docker engine directly without the Desktop application will be lighter-weight, and cases like this will work the way you expect.

Comment: @David Maze oh i forgot to tell my OS currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I just uninstalled Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly likely reason for this is that Docker Desktop does not have access to that location. Go to *Settings* in Docker Desktop, find the section on file or resource sharing. Ensure that the `/tmp/` directory is listed there.